# Make js canvas finish drawing within loop

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

I have a loop like this using `<canvas>`**:**

`for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    draw_something(); // clears canvas at start of function
}`

When this runs, nothing happens on the canvas until the loop finishes. The function `draw_something` is confirmed to work and displays something different each time.

Is there a way to make this draw to the canvas 1000 times? I don't want to use `setInterval` because I can't know how long `draw_something` will take.

Comment: show more code. Problem is in `draw_something` function, or in outer array function.

Comment: As the goal seems to be to have an animation, use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: I want to run a Buffon's noodle/needle simulation, and I want everything to be displayed.

Comment: read first comment

Comment: As I said, `draw_something` works in other contexts. I'm just running this loop from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(draw_something, 0)` seems to work, as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523342/canvas-redraws-only-after-loop-ends?rq=1).

Comment: You really should read the link I gave you about requestAnimationFrame.